# Parametrizing a matrix (and algorithm) by its orthogonal complement

Tags: algorithms, matrix, time-complexity

Given a large orthonormal matrix $U$, say $p\times p-k$ (with $k$ much smaller than $p$), is there an effficient way to parametrize $U$ by any matrix orthogonal complement (any orthonormal matrix whose columns span the space orthogonal to its own column space)?

The issue is that I have an iterative algorithm to find a matrix of the size of $U$, but it would be nice if there were a natural way to parametrize $U$ (and thus the algorithm) by the much smaller complement.

Comment: Presumably you miswrote "$n$" instead of "$p$" and you meant to say that "$p-k$ is much smaller than $p$"?

Comment: No, @whuber. We have an algorithm for a large matrix, but we would rather compute it by its much smaller complement. So k is small, and p-k is almost as big as p.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Presumably the "orthogonal complement" will be considered to be a $p\times k$ matrix.  But what then is "$n$"?  BTW, I think you will need to supply some details about what you mean by "orthogonal complement." Knowing just $k$ orthonormal $p$-vectors will not in general determine another $p-k$ orthonormal $p$-vectors uniquely; they only determine a $p-k$-dimensional complementary space. For instance, with $p=5$ and $k=1$ the orthonormal $p\times 1$ matrices form a manifold of $4$ dimensions whereas the orthonormal $p\times 4$ matrices have $6$ dimensions.

Comment: @whuber I made a typo, I wanted k much smaller than p. I modified the question. The specific matrix is not the issue, a matrix whose columns span the complementary space is the "orthogonal complement".

Comment: That's a confusing distinction: are you talking about the *matrix* or its *column space*? Regardless, how do you respond to the observation that there simply are not enough dimensions to carry out the parameterization you are asking for? If you want any answer besides "that's mathematically impossible," then you need to impose additional restrictions on $U$.

Comment: As you say, $k$ orthogonal vectors determine the complementary space completely. Both spaces can be represented by matrices with orthonormal columns. I am interested in the spaces themselves, and interested in the matrices as ways of practically representing these spaces. Obviously the representations are not unique.

Comment: OK, that's clear--but it is not the question that you are presently asking.  Your text still asks to "parameterize $U$" (twice), not just the space spanned by the columns of $U$.  Please fix up your question so it asks what you intend.

Comment: I added a slight change, but I don't understand your issue with the word parametrize. I mean that we are parametrize a space by some (non-unique) orthogonal matrix. I don't think parametrizations need to be unique.

Comment: The matrices correspond to orthonormal frames for the space, but they are not the same as the space itself. As an extreme example, the orthogonal $n$ by $n$ matrices form a manifold of dimension $n(n-1)/2$, but they all determine a single space.  Thus it takes $n(n-1)/2$ real parameters to parameterize the matrices but zero real parameters to parameterize the space itself. Your question, by not distinguishing the matrices from the spaces they span, still asks for something mathematically impossible.

Comment: But I don't claim they are the same in the question, just that you can represent the space by a matrix (not uniquely).